# What does mean Read-only file system while setting up superblock?

Tags: linux, read-only, superblock

I had created usb boot but it does being cause of read only file system.
Well I tried many ways to do but can not format or write new table so when I tried command :

```
mkfs /dev/sdd1
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdd1 contains a iso9660 file system labelled 'KAOS_20181223'
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
/dev/sdd1: Read-only file system while setting up superblock
```

So my question is what is `setting up superblock`
Is it being read only while setting blocks in memory?
And so can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you running this command as root?

Comment: Yes I do as root.

Comment: If I don't then it gives                                                                                       `mkfs /dev/sdd1
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Could not open /dev/sdd1: Permission denied`

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you set `/dev/sdd1` to read-write access first?

Comment: @Mast sorry I have bought new USB. So I think it is not possible to resolve blocked USB.